# In Javascript let can be updated but cannot be re-declared, const cannot be either, what exactly is the difference between updated and re-declared?

Tags: javascript, variables

*Let* and *const*, both block scoped, but *let* can be updated into the scope while *const* cannot, though neither can be re-declared into it. Objects assigned to a variable using *const* are still mutable, for example values in an array. Where my confusion lies is the concept of updating vs re-declaring a variable with these two, and how would it look in code. I'd appreciate any further explanation.

Comment: Re-declare: `let foo = 'abc'; let foo = 'def';` Reassign: `let foo = 'abc'; foo = 'def';`

Comment: thanks, that was all i was looking for, the syntax.